# Ajax live search takes time in greek but not in english

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have set in php file that searches the database

> $connect->set_charset('utf8');

to properly show greek characters
But in live search the searching in greek takes much more time than searching in english . I have 3000 records in database most of them in greek. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe an index problem... have you tried "EXPLAIN" query ?

Comment: it shows these 1  SIMPLE  new_record  ALL  NULL NULL NULL NULL 2942  NULL

Comment: You have to make an explain query without "set_charset('utf8')", and one with it, and compare your results. Please edit your question to add queries, the code you use, and the result. It's hard to read code in comments...

Comment: From what i remember i dont have indexed keys in db only primary and unique keys

Comment: Do you have any news ?

Comment: Sorry i am new and i dont know how to do that in my php